# How to set flags in microprocessor 8085 after IN instruction?

Tags: microprocessor, 8085

When microprocessor reads an input port, the instruction IN does not set any flag. If the input reading is zero, what logic instruction can be used to set the ZERO flag without affecting the contents of the accumulator?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to read the data into a register (with IN) and then compare the register with zero. A shortcut to compare with zero on some processors is to OR the register with itself, which will set the flags.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr Honniball! :) It worked!! Thank you!!

Comment: Sir, Can you please write the instructions. I got it but I'v some confusion. PLEASE :)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't actually know 8085 assembler! I think you need to do something like OR A,A after the IN, but that might be Z80 rather than 8085.

Comment: For standard 8085 opcodes do the "IN <port>" followed by "ORA A". The flags will be set according to the content of A.